# How to extract redirected url (href) of <a> tag having "href="javascript: return false" website redirects to a new url when clicked

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to get the redirected URL of the  tag, the URL we are redirected to by the website using javascript.

i am using (selenium) get_attribute('href'). The result I am getting is "javascript: return false", I need to get the redirected URL without visiting the redirected URL

This is a tag in HTML.

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="foto foto" id="attachment1" href="javascript: return false" title="Foto: Plintă, Set laterale 400x100mm, RAL7012">Foto: Plintă, Set laterale 400x100mm, RAL7012<span class="filelinks-filetype">(<span class="filelinks-fileext">jpg, </span> 4,15 MB)</span></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is a `href` in the `<a>` tag, but no url. What is your expected output?

Comment: href="javascript: return false"

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a').get_attribute("href")
```

should return this:

> 'javascript: return false'

Comment: yes but i need the url address, when this link is clicked it opens up into a new tab with a url address.

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan - That's why I asked you before what your expected output is!

Comment: i am sorry may be i did not clarify the things.i need the url of the new page which opens up when clicked.